# ffmpeg how to add a transparent watermark (png image) with opacity 50% in the video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, watermark

I am adding a watermark in the video and am using the code below:-

```
exec($ffmpegPath . " -i " . $tmpflvlinkFile .  " -i " . $water . " -    filter_complex \ 'overlay=180:150' -codec:a copy " . $flvlinkFile);
```

where variables $ffmpegPath is the path of ffmpeg, $tmpflvlinkFile is the source path video file , $water is the source path   of watermark image and $flvlinkFile is the path of target/resultant video file. 
I have even tried using transparent image for the watermark but still it did not help. All I want is the resultant video's watermark to be transparent (50% opaque) so that the view/seen behind the watermark is visible in the video.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: The question is too vague, you need to provide the command line that you invoked and all the ffmpeg messages that you get (including the informational, from the first ffmpeg line to the last).